# How to repair peeling corner bead?

Tags: drywall, walls, screws, screwdriver, corner-bead

I have this corner bead peeling.

[image]

How do I fix it in place? Do I drill a hole and anchor it with a screw?

[image]

This is inside the garage by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the overall condition of this outside corner:

The peeling of the joint compound appears caused by the corner being repeatedly hit.

The corner bead does not appear particularly damaged, deformed, or detached. One could drive a 1-1/4" to 1-1/2" drywall screw through it without pre-drilling (a 10d nail would be sufficient to create a "starter hole", if necessary).

There's not much point in making repairs on this corner unless something is done to prevent further damage (ie. install plastic/rubber baseboard and plastic/metal corner guards).

Comment: A screw would certainly hold it in place from any more damage, although when the screw goes in and sets, it will distort the metal a lot at the bottom since there is not much metal beyond where the screw will be placed. I would use a small headed nail (4d siding nail or underlayment nail) or drywall nail and be done with it. A +1 on the answer since it is still a simple remedy, just use caution with the screw, or it will create more separation than you have now....

Comment: Thanks @Jack Will it distort it at the bottom of the screw by making the metal sort of curve away from the wall (at the bottom of the nail) or will it distort the metal at the top of the screw? Like, how will the separation take place? :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I used to use screws, and I still do in a pinch, It wrinkles the metal between the edge of the corner bead and the screw head. In order to get the screw flush with the metal, even when using the large holes that are pre-punched in the corner bead (like where your arrow is pointing to in the bottom drawing), the metal distorts. It distorts worse at the bottom. The flat metal corner, not the bent corner, will bend out a bit, needed to be tapped back into the surface with a hammer when it does.